# Create a raster of uniform value over a uniform grid from the partial intersect of raster over that grid?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I need to generate a time series of data over different grids in ArcGIS.
Here I am intersecting the raster file from a polygon shapefile of irregular shape, which gives a final raster file as shown in figure.

[image]

Here, I want to generate a raster file which assign the values to Grid 1, 2, and 3 from the partially intersected raster.

Once I could do this, I will be getting the raster something like shown below.

[image]
I am trying to this as I have center grid points for all the polygon and I could extract values to those point by doing this, and have a time series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending one whole night I could solve the problem, hope it will help my  other colleagues,

Step 1: Convert the raster to points

Step 2: "Spatial Join" the polygon grid shape file shown with the generated shape file.

Step 3: A new polygon grid shape file will be created that will have the raster values as required.

Step 4: Convert the obtained polygon shape file to raster for further processing.

Below is the arcpy code for Step 2

```
import arcpy

join_features = 'Path/To/Point.shp'
target_features = 'Path/To//Fishnet.shp'
out_feature_class = 'Path/To/Fishnet_spatial_join.shp'

arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(target_features, join_features, out_feature_class)
```